# GridSearchCV verbosity is not showing time elapsed for each step

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I'm doing hyper parameter optimization using `GridSearchCV`, I set `n_jobs = -1` to use all cores, and `verbose` to 1 to get the time elapsed periodically, problem is that I don't get any log except for:

`Fitting 5 folds for each of 256 candidates, totalling 1280 fits`

This happened after upgrading sklearn to version 1.0.1, version 0.22.1 worked with no problems.

Here is the code sample:

```
params = {'n_estimators':[5,10,15,50],
                'max_depth':[5,10,50,100],
                'min_samples_split':[2,3,4,5],
                'min_samples_leaf':[1,2,3,4]
         }
model = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)
grid_obj = GridSearchCV(model, params, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',n_jobs=-1, 
                        refit = 'neg_mean_squared_error', 
                        cv=5, verbose=1, return_train_score=True)

gif_fit = grid_obj.fit(X.drop(['Month'],axis=1), np.array(y).ravel())
```

Also the console outputted this, and I don't know what it means:
[image]
I ran this code previously on the same settings, except for the `params` dictionary and the output was:
[image]

How to enable the log as previously mentioned?

I tried setting `n_jobs = 1` and it was the same.